# How deal with this issue in SQL with Groupby

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql, case

I have this data called pdays:

```
id|time|date_time| type_id
1  2    2016-03-05 1
2  5    2016-03-05 1
3  3    2016-03-06 2
4  7    2016-03-07 3
5  2    2016-03-10 1
6  1    2016-03-12 3
```

I would like to calculate the average number of time SUM(time) for weekdays and weekends grouped by type_id

The output expect like this:

```
type_id| weekday_time|weekends_time
1        7            2
2        3            0
3        7            1
```

This is my thoughts:

First I need to extract date number from date_time; Second, identify the date number whether falls into (5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27) which are weekend numbers (note: This data presents a one month case, so I do not need to worry about the changes of weekend date numbers in next month); Finally, do the aggregation and grouping on type_id

```
CASE WHEN pday.date IN(5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27) THEN 'weekend' ELSE 'weekday' END
```

This is the case part I think I should use.

Comment: Your case statement immediately falls apart when the next month rolls around and the 5th and 6th are not on the weekend. Each RDBMS has some form of a DATEPART function that will return the day of the week and you can glean weekday vs weekend from that.

Comment: It is just a one month case, so I do not need to worry about the change of numbers in next month

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, Sql Server, etc

Comment: i am using spark.sql

Answer (score 1):

First, your output appears to be wrong. Type_id 3 has both a weekend and a weekday entry, but you show one of the output values as 0.

This should get you what you want in SQL Server and it is very close to other RDBMS's. If you update your RBDMS, I'll change:

```
;with cte AS (
select type_id, 
CASE WHEN pday.date IN(5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27) THEN 'weekday' ELSE 'weekend' END AS day_type, 
SUM(time) AS time_sum
FROM pdays
GROUP BY 
type_id, 
CASE WHEN pday.date IN(5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27) THEN 'weekday' ELSE 'weekend' END
)

SELECT type_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN day_type = 'weekday' THEN time_sum ELSE 0 END) AS 'weekday_time',
SUM(CASE WHEN day_type = 'weekend' THEN time_sum ELSE 0 END) AS 'weekend_time'
FROM cte 
GROUP BY [type_id]
```

Comment: I would like to know whether pday.date would work if the type of data is VARCHAR(10). Thx